# Laravel 8 Jestream Notifiable Sending email to non existing user does not work

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am using Laravel 8 Jetstream.

Given that I am using an additional and external database, I need to send email notifications to users, whose info is in that external database, where the `email` column name is different; let's say "electronicmail".

In [the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) it says:

> Remember, you may use the Notifiable trait on any of your models. You
> are not limited to only including it on your User model.

So I got this external model:

**ExternalUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\ExternalDatabase;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class ExternalUser extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * External DB connection
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection='externalissima';

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table='External-users';


    /**
     * Indicates whether or not the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

That external `External-users` table does not have the `email` column, but as `electronicmail`.

So, whenever I use:

```
$ext_user->notify(new \App\Notifications\Test());
```

The `\App\Notifications\Test()` notification class is not working, since I guess because there's no exact `email` column name.

Then how do I customize the email column to make it work?

After hours of searching, I have read also in the same docs that you can make use of [on-demand notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications) like so:

```
Route::get('notification', function (){
    Auth()->user()->notify(new \App\Notifications\Test()); //THIS IS WORKING

    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::route('email',
        ['tester@mail.com','John Doe']
    )->notify(new \App\Notifications\Test()); //THIS, what I need, IS NOT WORKING, why???
});
```

And my test notification looks like:

**Notifications/Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class Test extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Test notification')
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

In my case, the notifications for the `models/User.php` are working fine.

**However**,

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::route('email',
            ['tester@mail.com','John Doe']
        )->notify(new \App\Notifications\Test());
```

this is not working with on demand notifications with a custom email, why?

How do I fix this? What am I missing?

Comment: Did u try to add accesor getEmailAttribute() to ExternalUser?

Comment: also you can look here, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#customizing-the-recipient. Document explain how customize which email address is used to deliver the notification

Comment: @Maksim Wow! It's working now! Большое спасибо, амиго! But I still wonder, why doesn't the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::route('email')` work?

Comment: @Prospero It also works! Thx! But I still wonder, why doesn't the Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::route('email', ['custom@mail.com']) work at all?

Comment: The only I see is you aren't passing the notification instance like ->notify(new \App\Notifications\Test($external_user)